# MVC 4 Refresh a PartialView Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, refresh, partial-views

I am currently developing a website with CRUD functionality. I am using the below javascript code to display a message after the Add, Edit, or Delete has been completed successfully.

```
function addSuccess(data) {
    if (data.Success == true) {
        $('#addDialog').dialog('close');
        $('#commonMessage').html("Process Complete");
        $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);
    }
    else {
        $("#add-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
        $("#add-message").show();
    }
}
```

However, I am rendering results on a partial view containing a webGrid. In this case, a tabular list of products are in this Partial View. After (let's say) an Edit Process has been completed, I want the edited field to reflect after the Edit Dialog has been closed. My problem is, I don't know how to refresh a partialview without affecting the whole page.

Can someone please point me to a good way to do this? Thank you very much!

---

**EDIT:**

Below is how I add items to my grid. Please note that this entire code is inside my PartialView. Thank you!

```
@{
    MyStore.Business.Manager.ProductsManager repository = new MyStore.Business.Manager.ProductsManager ();

    List<MyStore.Data.Products> ProductsList = repository.GetAllProducts(ViewData["StoreCode"].ToString());

    var grid = new WebGrid(ProductsList );

    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
            @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
                htmlAttributes: new { id = "DataTable" },
                headerStyle: "header",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("ProductCode", style: "width: 400px;"),
                    grid.Column("Name", style: "width: 400px"),
                    grid.Column("Price", style: "width: 100px;"),
                    grid.Column("", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "_Edit", new { RecordID = item.RecordID }, new { @class = "editLink" })</text>, style: "width: 100px"),
                    grid.Column("", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "_Delete", new { RecordID = item.RecordID }, new { @class = "editLink" })</text>, style: "width: 100px")
                                                 ));                                                      
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jquery `ajax` to reload the content

```
if (data.Success == true) {
    $('#addDialog').dialog('close');
    $('#commonMessage').html("Process Complete")
                   .delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);

    $("#yourContainerDiv").load("Url.Action("GetProducts ","Items")")

}
```

Assuming `yourContainerDiv` is the Div /table where you have the markup of the Grid and Your `GetProducts` action method of `Items` controller returns the markup of the grid.

and if you are doing the Save/Update in a button click event, Make sure to stop the default form submit behaviour by using `peventDefault` method

```
$("#someButtonId").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //Save data or whatever ...
});
```

**EDIT:** *After seting the updated question.*

Why are you mixing your UI (`view`) with the `code`. Keep it seperate.

Have an `action` to get the data and pass that to a strongly typed view

```
public ActionResult GetProducts()
{
   var repository = new MyStore.Business.Manager.ProductsManager ();
   var productList = repository.GetAllProducts(ViewData["StoreCode"].ToString());
   return View(productList);    
}
```

Now have a view(`GetProducts.cshtml`) which is strongly typed to Lost of Products class.

```
@model MyStore.Data.Products
@{
  Layout=null;
}
<table>
   @foreach(var item in Model)
   {
     <tr>
      <td>@item.ProductCode</td>
      <td>@item.Name</td>
      <td>@item.Price</td>
     </tr>
   }
</table>
```

Personally I keep my Entity/Model name as Singular like `Customer` /`Product`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response! Can you please explain the `GetProducts` and `Items` part? I don't seem to get it. Thank you!!!

Comment: Does this mean that `GetProducts` is the name of a method from the `Items` Controller which returns a ListofProducts to be bounded to the webGrid? Because if it does mean like that then I have to say that I am not doing it that way. Please see my edit above. Thank you! :)